# How should I partition my HDD?

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I am using ubuntu on my notebook with 4Gb RAM and 300Gb HDD and my layout is:

```
/ - 15Gb ext4 (4.5Gb used)
/home - 280Gb ext4 (200Gb used)
/swap - 2Gb
```

I have recently built a PC with 8Gb RAM and a 1Tb HDD. Now I am curious as to how  I should partition my HDD, so that I dual-boot (Win7 + Ubuntu). I was thinking:

```
boot - 200Mb 
/ - 10Gb xfs
/home - 1000Gb xfs
ntfs - 200Gb
```

No swap because i don't use hibernate at all. Ubuntu will be primary system, Win7 is only for a few fresh games which cannot run with Wine. The only questions:

1. Is `/boot` needed?
2. Is **xfs** better for `/root` and `/home`?
3. And isn't it bad that `/home` is so big? If yes, should i made `/usr`,
   `/var`, `/tmp` or something else?

Comment: I think you made a typo with the `/home` directory, coz 1000GB is almost equal to 1TB itself. Please correct the question if so.

Comment: only thing I would change: make /home/ 25Gb and put the remaining Gbs in a new data partition.If you make that ext2 you can share it with windows too ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. `xfs` doesn't need a separate `/boot` partition, grub2 can boot off of
   `xfs`
2. You won't find a single answer. Google it - everyone will say
   different. Any particular reason to use it?
3. For dual booting it's best (IMHO) to make the biggest partition `ntfs`
   and share it by simply soft-linking the stuff you need.

   So I for example have a `ntfs` partition containing the folders Downloads, Movies, Music and Documents. Right-click and create link copy the link over `/home/Downloads` etc. works nice.

In Win 7 you can use the library function to always use those folders.

So it's

- 10-30 GB `ntfs` for win 7 (OS)
- $(therest) GB `ntfs` for data (biggest)
- 10-30 GB `ext4` for Ubuntu
- (optional) one `ext4` for `/home` (doesn't need to be big though, the data is on `ntfs` anyway).

Comment: In this case it is wiser to give the larger space to Ubuntu, because he said he wants Win7 only for some games, not for documents. When answering, take details into consideration please.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that Win 7 takes nearly 7 GB in a standard install whereas Ubuntu takes 3-4 plus less for programs aferwards (because of shared libraries). Details considered ;)

Answer (score 1):

For dual booting you are just better off getting a second HDD and switching the boot order in the bios when you want to use it.